# I am trying to get the numbers from the rating and sum them up to calculate average but it prints the details separately

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried placing the array outside and inside. If i place it outside, it only picks up one value. If i place it inside it prints the values differently so when i try to add the values together. it still prints separately. I have attached the firebase structure as an image. I am very new to both Kotlin and Firebase

```
private fun loadAverageRating() {
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    databaseReference = database?.reference!!.child("profile")
    val storereference = databaseReference?.child(shopid.text.toString())?.child("rating")

  
    storereference?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapShot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapShot.exists()) {
                dataSnapShot.children.forEach {

                    for (promoSnapshot in it.children) {
                        //averageRating = promoSnapshot.getValue(String::class.java)?.toFloat()!!
                        averageRating = promoSnapshot.getValue().toString().toFloat()

                        val total = listOf(averageRating)
                        //averageArrayRating!!.add(averageRating!!)

                        Log.d("test",total.sum().toString())
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            return
        }
    })
}
```

[Firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVzam.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way this can work if you're declaring the variable that will hold the average inside the loop, because it's going to be reset on each individual item.

And I can't comment on what was wrong when you had it outside the loop because you didn't share that code. If I was going to iterate to find a sum, it would look like this:

```
for (child in dataSnapShot.children) {
    var total = 0f
    for (grandchild in child.children) {
        total += grandchild.value.toString().toFloat()
    }
    val average = total / child.children.size
    Log.d("avg","The average of $child is $average")
}
```

An alternate way instead of iterating it is to use `sumOf` to select the values that you want to add, and it totals them for you (actually it is still iterating behind the scenes). Keep in mind it works with Doubles instead of Floats. Then just divide by the size to get the average.

```
for (child in dataSnapShot.children) {
    val promos = child.children
    val sum = promos.sumOf { it.value.toString().toDouble() }
    val average = sum / promos.size
    Log.d("avg","The average of $child is $average")
}
```

Comment: hey brother, thank you for the solution but there seems to be a problem with child.children.size part .. Android Studio is not allowing me to use .size

Comment: and the values are still not adding up .. it is displayed separately.. exactly the way my previous code worked .....